# Fire javascript every x page load, for example, every 3rd page

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this question has been answered, before, but my searches are coming up empty.

I have a simple jQuery function (that slides in a box after the page has been scrolled down).  It works fine.

However, how do I set cookies, or other method, to make it execute on the first page load and, then, on every 3rd page load of the session, after that?

Comment: I wouldn't use cookies for this; I'd use something more modern like LocalStorage. Try something with that, and if you can't get it working, edit your attempted code into the question and we'll help you from there.

Comment: Why don't you set a cookie then increment it, and try to divide it to 3 then fire function based on that result?

Comment: A cookie would work fine; LocalStorage would work fine. I would consider firing the JS based on time (if time passed > some threshold) maybe.

Answer (score 5):

A little snippet like this should work for you.

```js
(function () {
  // Get the countdown from localStorage
  var countdown = Number(window.localStorage.getItem('countdown'));
  
  // If countdown isn’t set it or if it has
  // run a couple times it’ll be `0`
  // Either way—we reset countdown and run the function
  if (!countdown) {
    countdown = 3;
    // Run the function
  }

  // Update the countdown
  window.localStorage.setItem('countdown', countdown - 1);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

These are both very instructive answers (my javascript skill is at the piece-it-together level).  If it's helpful to someone, even though the question was for a javascript solution, I realized there might be a PHP solution, as well.

This worked, too:

```
<?php   //Slide-in ad will show every x pages
$slide_ad_frequency=3;
session_start();
//increase the already-set counter by 1 or initiate the counter with a value of 1
if( isset( $_SESSION['counter'] ) )
{
   $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
}
else
{
   $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
}
    //If counter equals the ad frequency setting
if($_SESSION['counter'] % $slide_ad_frequency == 0) : ?>

    ... Code to execute ...

<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store the count of window loads on the [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) so that data won't be lost on every reload. The data will be cleared when the tab is closed. If you want your data to not expire when the session ends, you should instead use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage); both have the same implementation.

```
window.onload = doSomething;

function doSomething() {
    let count =  sessionStorage.getItem('noOfPageLoads');
    if( count ) {  //if count is not null, increment it
        count++;
        sessionStorage.setItem('noOfPageLoads', count);  //update the local storage
    }
    else {   //if count is null, it's the first load, so put it in the local storage
        count = 0;
        sessionStorage.setItem('noOfPageLoads', count);
    }
    console.log('noOfPageLoads = '+ count)
    if( count===0 || count===3 ) {
        console.log('do something now');
        //do what you want here
    }
}
```